Test class coverage issue
I have an apex method i have to write test class for that
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static userWithStateTerritoryDetails userWithStateTerritoriesDetails(String programType,String programId){
//fetch the account details
objAccount=getAccount_Apex();
//it will hold the current logged in user id
String userId = UserInfo.getUserId();
//fetch the shopping cart details for the logged in user to capture the state long drink budget territory id in the shopping cart, we are doing this because we need to show the selected value in the dropdown when it is already selected
ShoppingCart__c shoppingCart = [SELECT Id,State_Long_Drink_Budget_Territory__c FROM ShoppingCart__c
WHERE Active__c=true AND CreatedById=:UserInfo.getUserId() AND
CartStatus__c='Open' AND Inventory_Seasonal_Program__c =:programType AND Program__c=:programId AND Account__c = :objAccount.Id];
//capture the state long drink budget territory id from the shopping cart and store it in a container variable budgetstateTerritoryIdInShoppingCart
Id budgetstateTerritoryIdInShoppingCart = shoppingCart.State_Long_Drink_Budget_Territory__c;
// we are fetch the chair details for the  userId and store in a container chairDetailsList
List<Chair__c> chairDetailsList = [SELECT Id,Chair_Name__c,State_Long_Drink_Budget_Territory__c,State_Long_Drink_Budget_Territory__r.Id,State_Long_Drink_Budget_Territory__r.State__r.State_Name__c FROM Chair__c WHERE User__r.Id=:userId AND Account__c=:objAccount.Id];
System.debug('chairDetailsList----'+chairDetailsList);
//return the userWithTerritoryDetails which will have territory id in shopping cart and list of chair details
return new userWithStateTerritoryDetails(budgetstateTerritoryIdInShoppingCart,chairDetailsList);
} 

This is my apex method
@isTest
private class LongDrinkChairFinancialBudget_ApexTest {
static Account acct;
static Program__c program;
static State_Long_Drink_Budget_Territory__c statelongDrinkbudget;
static User communityUser;

@testSetup static void setupData() {
    
    List<Account> testAccts = new List<Account>();
    Account acct = new Account(Name='Long Drink');
    insert acct ;
    Contact contact=new Contact(LastName='Testing',AccountId=acct.Id);
    insert contact;
    Profile profile=[SELECT Name FROM Profile WHERE Name='Customer Community Plus User' LIMIT 1];
    
    User communityUser = new User(Alias = 'standt', Email='standarduser@testorg.com', 
                                  EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Testing', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', 
                                  LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = profile.Id, 
                                  TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='standarduser@testorg.com',ContactId=contact.Id,
                                  International_Address_Accessible__c=true);
    
    insert communityUser;
    List<Country__c> countryList = new List<Country__c>();
    Country__c countryUSA=new Country__c(Active__c=true , Country_Code__c='countryCode' , Country_Name__c='USA');
    insert countryUSA;
    Country__c countryInternational=new Country__c(Active__c=true , Country_Code__c='CA' , Country_Name__c='Canada',Is_It_International_Country__c=true);
    insert countryInternational;
    List<State__c> stateList = new List<State__c>();
    State__c state = new State__c(State_Name__c='testState', Active__c = true, Country__c=countryUSA.id ,State_Code__c='SA');
    insert state ;
    State__c stateInternational= new State__c(State_Name__c='testState', Active__c = true, Country__c=countryInternational.id ,State_Code__c='LA');
    insert stateInternational ;
    Territory__c territory = new Territory__c (Territory_Name__c='testTerritory',Active__c=true,Account__c=acct.Id);
    insert territory;
    States_Territory__c stateTerritory = new States_Territory__c (State__c = state.Id,Territory__c= territory.Id);
    insert stateTerritory;
    Users_Territory__c usersTerritory = new Users_Territory__c (Territory__c= territory.Id,User__c=UserInfo.getUserId());
    insert usersTerritory;
    Brand__c brand = new Brand__c (Brand_Name__c='BrandNameSelect',Active__c=true,Account__c=acct.Id);
    insert brand;
    Program__c program = new Program__c(Name__c='Holiday Test',Start_Date__c=System.today(),Closing_Date__c=System.today().addDays(3),In_Market_Date__c=System.today().addDays(5));
    insert program;
    Item_Type__c itemType= new Item_Type__c(Item_Type__c='itemTypeSelect',Active__c=true,Account__c=acct.Id);
    insert itemType;
    POS_Item__c posItem= new POS_Item__c (Item_No__c='Test-No-01',Item_Name__c='testPosItemName',Available_Stock__c=10,
                                          Account__c=acct.Id,Brand__c=brand.Id,Type_of_Item__c=itemType.Id,Active__c=true);
    insert posItem;
    
    POS_Item__c posItem2= new POS_Item__c (Item_No__c='Test-No-02',Item_Name__c='testPosItemName',Available_Stock__c=10,
                                           Account__c=acct.Id,Brand__c=brand.Id,Type_of_Item__c=itemType.Id,Active__c=true);
    insert posItem2;
    
    Facility__c facility = new Facility__c(Facility_ID__c=1,Facility_Name__c='Buffalo');
    insert facility;

    Long_Drink_Budget_Territory__c longDrinkBudgetTerritory = new Long_Drink_Budget_Territory__c(Account__c=acct.Id,Budget_Territory_Name__c='Sbudget',Is_Active__c=true);
    insert longDrinkBudgetTerritory;
    State_Long_Drink_Budget_Territory__c statelongDrinkbudget = new State_Long_Drink_Budget_Territory__c(Long_Drink_Budget_Territory__c=longDrinkBudgetTerritory.Id,State__c=state.Id);
    insert statelongDrinkbudget;        
    ShoppingCart__c shoppingCart = new ShoppingCart__c(Account__c = acct.Id, CartStatus__c = 'Open',Inventory_Seasonal_Program__c='Inventory',Program__c=program.Id,State_Long_Drink_Budget_Territory__c=statelongDrinkbudget.Id,Active__c=true);
    insert shoppingCart;
    
    ShoppingCartItems__c shoppingCartItem = new ShoppingCartItems__c(ShoppingCart__c = shoppingCart.Id , POS_Item__c = posItem.Id);
    insert shoppingCartItem;
    
    Carrier__c carrier = new Carrier__c(Carrier_Name__c='FedEx',Billing_Type__c='third party');
    insert carrier;
    
    Shipping_Method__c shippingMethod = new Shipping_Method__c(Account__c=acct.Id , Active__c=true , Default__c=true, ApprovalRequired__c=true , Shipping_Method_Name__c='shippingMethod1',Carrier__c=carrier.Id,Mode__c='Ground');
    insert shippingMethod;
    
    Shipping_Method__c shippingMethod2 = new Shipping_Method__c(Account__c=acct.Id , Active__c=true , ApprovalRequired__c=false , Default__c=true , Shipping_Method_Name__c='shippingMethod2', DisplayOrder__c = 1,Carrier__c=carrier.Id,Mode__c='Ground');
    insert shippingMethod2;
    
    
    AddressBook__c addressBook = new AddressBook__c(Account__c=acct.Id , Destination_Name__c='destinationName' , 
                                                    Shipto_Company__c='shipToCompany', State__c=state.Id) ;
    insert addressBook;
    
    
}

 @isTest
private static void controllerTest()
{
        Test.startTest();
            LongDrinkChairFinancialBudgetDetail_Apex.getAccount_Apex();
            LongDrinkChairFinancialBudgetDetail_Apex.userWithStateTerritoriesDetails('Inventory', program.Id);
        Test.stopTest();


}

}
This is my test class
When i run this i am getting an error for the line
ShoppingCart__c shoppingCart = [SELECT Id,State_Long_Drink_Budget_Territory__c FROM ShoppingCart__c
WHERE Active__c=true AND CreatedById=:UserInfo.getUserId() AND
CartStatus__c='Open' AND Inventory_Seasonal_Program__c =:programType AND Program__c=:programId AND Account__c = :objAccount.Id];
I tried to run my test class as an community user as well
System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
Thanks in advance

Most likely subject would be that the objAccount is null, but we would need the code for getAccount_Apex() to be able to check.
